# rust - methods as argument including a self reference

Tags: rust

I have the following problem:
I have two structs A and B, A implements a method, which takes another method as argument. I then create an instance of A within B. I then call the method of A with a method of B as argument. However, the passed method of B contains self as argument, since I have to access some other fields of B within the passed method.

My current plan would be to pass the method itself and self referencing an instance of B to the method in A. However, I struggle with the type definitions. I can hardcode the type of the second parameter to be B, however, I would like to keep it open, in case a struct C would also like to use the method in A. I therefore would like to set the type of the second parameter to the type of the struct, where the method in the first parameter is originating. Is there a way for achieving this? I was thinking about generics, however, I was not yet able to implement it.

Edit: added a minimal example in rust playground. What bothers me about this code, is, that I want to get rid of the hard coded &B in some_func_a, since this does not work with struct C.

```
struct A {}

impl A {
    fn some_func_a(&self, passed_fn: fn(&B, i32), cur_self: &B) {
        passed_fn(cur_self, 21);
    }
}

struct B {
    some_val: i32,
}

struct C {
    some_val: u32, // different field here than in B
}

impl B {
    fn call_fn_in_a(&self, a: A) {
        a.some_func_a(B::some_func_b, self);
    }

    fn some_func_b(&self, passed_val: i32) {
        println!("The value is {}, passed was {}", self.some_val, passed_val)
    }
}

impl C {
    fn call_fn_in_a(&self, a: A) {
        // this line here breaks, since &B is hard coded
        a.some_func_a(C::some_func_c, self);
    }

    fn some_func_c(&self, passed_val: i32) {
        println!("this is a new function, val is {}, passed was {}", self.some_val, passed_val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {};
    let b = B {
        some_val: 42,
    };
    
    let b = B {
        some_val: 42,
    };
    b.call_fn_in_a(a);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=53ac44cb660d180b3c7351e394355692

Comment: can you show us a minimal example? if it is with a link to https://play.rust-lang.org/ even better.

Comment: Sure, sorry, should have directly added an example

Comment: Something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc869e360935888b0f06a699eb82caa0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) instead of a function pointer.  This would allow you to eliminate the extra parameter of `A::some_func_a()` altogether:

```
impl A {
    fn some_func_a(&self, passed_fn: impl FnOnce(i32) -> ()) {
        passed_fn(21);
    }
}
```

Now we can call this function with any closure matching the call signature.  For example:

```
impl B {
    fn call_fn_in_a(&self, a: A) {
        a.some_func_a(|v| self.some_func_b(v));
    }

    fn some_func_b(&self, passed_val: i32) {
        println!("The value is {}, passed was {}", self.some_val, passed_val)
    }
}
```

And likewise for `C`.

Now there are *no* restrictions on what extra data the function needs.  Before there wasn't even a way to express the situation where the callback didn't need the reference parameter.  Now it doesn't matter because the closure can capture what it needs, and it's no longer `A::some_func_a()`'s responsibility.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=861c940cdf3a47564042f5dd1aa60b56))

---

Side note: you probably want your `call_fn` methods to take the `A` by reference (`&A`), not by value.  Otherwise calling these functions consumes the `A` value, requiring you to make another one to call the functions again.